# Facing problem of creating File Streams for file on Network Folder

Tags: c++, windows, file, createfile

We have Qt, C++ desktop application and we use file streams(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-streams) to write metadata of file.

We use following code to access the file stream:

```
HANDLE hStream;
QString localFilePath = physicalFilePath + ":AppData:$DATA"
hStream = CreateFile(localFilePath.toStdWString().c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
```

This works fine when we work on folder within the same machine. But, when our “physicalFilePath” is of network folder i.e. \nas\Test\TestFile.docx , CreateFile returns the error code 2 i.e. ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
I even tried Defining an MS-DOS Device Name,  so tried

```
TCHAR szDriveLetter = L”G:”;
TCHAR pszNTDevice = L”\\nas\Test\TestFile.docx”;
DWORD fResult = DefineDosDevice(DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH | DDD_NO_BROADCAST_SYSTEM, szDriveLetter, pszNTDevice);
```

This returns 1 or nonzero i.e. success, but when I use

```
std::wstring localFilePath = L"G:\\Test.txt:AdoddleData:$DATA";
HANDLE hStream = CreateFile(localFilePath.c_str(),
                GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_ALWAYS,
                0,
                NULL);

    if (hStream == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            CloseHandle(hStream);
    }
```

It returns error code 123, ERROR_INVALID_NAME?

Please suggest me how can I create a file stream for a file on a network folder.

Comment: What metadata are you trying to write? Can you open this file using regular Qt classes, like QFile? If you can, you can try using handle() from that.

Comment: You are trying to use the alternate data stream feature of the NTFS file system.  The odds that this can work on a networked drive are not good.  Primarily because the networked drive isn't NTFS, secondarily because the network redirector doesn't support it.  Try it from the [command line first](https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds).

Comment: @Dan M, I tried to open file using QFile with the same stream name but it didn't help. QFile's open fails for such file. I want to write metadata like project id, folder id and document id, working folder which our application requires.

Comment: Consider that you merely found the first way this info can get lost.  There are *many* more, like storing the file on a memory stick, putting it in a .zip file, storing it in the cloud with DropBox, Google Drive, OneDrive, etc.  If you can't afford to lose this info then you should not use alternative data streams.  Consider the simpler way, creating another file to store this data with a different filename extension.

Comment: @Hans Passant, Yes, you are right, when I tried this on command line after using "subst" command, and then tried to write using file streams, it gave the same error "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Note that ":" is an invalid filename character only in Microsoft's file systems. Other file systems are free to allow it, and many do. This explains the fact that you're getting a not-found error (2) instead of an invalid-name error (123).

Comment: Also, you're misusing `DefineDosDevice`. "\\nas\Test\TestFile.docx" is a DOS UNC path, so it's wrong to use the flag `DDD_RAW_TARGET_PATH`. Also, for this to make sense as a drive, you should target the parent directory, not the file. If for some reason you needed to use a NT path, the equivalent is "\??\UNC\nas\Test". Notice that this uses the NTAPI local-device prefix "\??\" instead of the WINAPI prefix "\\?\".